# How can I extract values from the XML::Simple's data structure?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

I'm trying to figure out how to parse the `<current></current>` values from the first 2 (`37%` and `61.8F`) in this XML. I can't figure it out since it seems that they have the same field names and are all under 'sensor'... any help would be appreciated...

Code in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::Simple;


$url = 'http://localhostmachine/output/XML/output.xml';

# create object
my $xml = XML::Simple->new();

# read XML file
$data = $xml->XMLin(get($url));

# print output
print Dumper($data);
```

Output of XML file that I am reading in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="wpman.xsl"?>
<watchport>
<title>
<TxtTitle>Location#1</TxtTitle>
</title>
<sensor>
<type>Combo Sensor (Humidity)</type>
<name>ComboSensor000</name>
<status>OK</status>
<current>37%</current>
<high>42 (10/19/2009 @ 04:05PM)</high>
<low>28 (10/17/2009 @ 11:26AM)</low>
</sensor>
<sensor>
<type>Combo Sensor (Temperature)</type>
<name>ComboSensor000</name>
<status>OK</status>
<current>61.6F</current>
<high>65.8 (10/17/2009 @ 11:26AM)</high>
<low>60.1 (10/19/2009 @ 04:00PM)</low>
</sensor>
<sensor>
<type> </type>
<name> </name>
<status> </status>
<current> </current>
</sensor>
<sensor>
<type>Updated: 10/19/2009 @ 05:47 PM</type>
<name>(Updated every 2 minutes)</name>
<status> </status>
<current> </current>
</sensor>
</watchport>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: My mistake, I meant this is the input XML. Sorry!

Comment: @Josh G. Please `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
print $data->{sensor}[0]{current};
print $data->{sensor}[1]{current};
```

Comment: omg, it was that simple!? I was trying $data->{sensor[0]}

Thank you so much Tim!

Answer (score 7):

Since you've already got the answer, here are some links you might find helpful.

They give a good introduction to working with references and complex data structures, with plenty of examples.

- [The Perl Data Structures
  Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [The References Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

I'm not trying to dismissively throw an RTFM at you, please don't take my response in that way. Perl has a lot of docs, it can be hard to find your way around them when starting out. [How to RTFM](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=78752) is a good resource that helps demystify the manual.